# Jmeter not considering local domain in Server name or IP while test script recorder with Mozilla

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter 4.0 for the first time and when I am trying for test recording with Mozilla linked to Jmeter, i am able to record .net and .com sites but I am unable to test my application deployed in the server and having the URL with server domain which is not a generic site like .net and .com.

Please let me know how I can test my server's domain URLs through Jmeter.

Comment: My guess..Check proxy configuration, Sniff traffic from your application using fiddler or any sniffing tool. Jmeter can work with IP address also. Try accessing application with IP and then record...

Comment: make sure your proxy is not configured to bypass local intranet addresses (e.g. using IP mask)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is a proxy issue, in order to isolate it, if possible and then host the application on the local box and then try to record it, it will work.!!